# after a variable change to 1, call something.. javascript

Tags: javascript

So Basicly if i click the burtton, it should change the variables to 1.
However, it dosen't print out "It's happening now" as it should.

Could someone please explain what's wrong with this??

Best regards daniel.

```
var reg_uname_done = 0;
var reg_pword1_done = 0;
var reg_pword2_done = 0;
var reg_email_done = 0;


$("#first_nav_bar li:first").click(function(event) {
    reg_uname_done = 1;
    reg_pword1_done = 1;
    reg_pword2_done = 1;
    reg_email_done = 1;
}); 



if(reg_pword1_done === 1 && reg_pword2_done === 1 && reg_email_done === 1 && reg_uname_done === 1) {
    console.log('its happening now');
}
```

Comment: Move the `if` condition inside the click function.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want it to be indside that.
I just want it to check all the time.. it's not possible like that?

Comment: Once the document is loaded it will run that if-statement and never check it again unless the document is reloaded, effectively resetting the values back to 0.

Comment: I suppose you could use a `setInterval` to check the values over a given period.

Comment: Dont understand why the downvotes.....

Comment: Yeh me neither, i suppose because it was a stupid question to begin with..
But i guess we all have to learn it somehow :P

Comment: Keep in mind your if statement as currently coded will fail. You have `reg_email_done && reg_uname_done`. These are not boolean values but are numbers.

Comment: Ah yeh, it's changed in script, i just forgot to edit it here when i copy/pasted.
My bad

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not happening is b/c the js file is going down, and you haven't "clicked" the `<li>` element yet, therefore your variables are still equal to 0. You have to set a function inside of that event.

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xajeus3k/1/)

```
var reg_uname_done = 0;
var reg_pword1_done = 0;
var reg_pword2_done = 0;
var reg_email_done = 0;

$("#first_nav_bar li:first").click(function (event) {
    reg_uname_done = 1;
    reg_pword1_done = 1;
    reg_pword2_done = 1;
    reg_email_done = 1;

    check();
})

function check() {
    if (reg_pword1_done === 1 && reg_pword2_done === 1 && reg_email_done && reg_uname_done) {
        console.log('its happening now');
    }
}
```